# how to add a dynamic/unique ID to haml cycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, haml

How can I add dynamic and unique, CSS ID, within a cycle with haml ?

I thought something like: %td.tag-house."#{repo.id}" which is a hash like 4e23114b1d41c80f180005b2, but doesn't work.

```
...
    %tbody
      - @watched_repos.each do |repo|
        %tr.row
          %td= repo.id
          %td= repo.description
          - if current_user.nickname = 'lgs'
            %td.tag-house."#{repo.id}"= repo.tags
```

Comment: Do you mean a "cycle" or "loop"? "cicle" isn't a word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
%td{:class => "tag-house #{repo.id}"}
```